# Why the CSS is not working on last button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could you please tell me why CSS is not working on last button. Actually I give border to last button of button bar. I also apply important to that last button or of bar. But it is not taking CSS. Here is my last button CSS:

```
.button_account_bar > .button:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 8px!important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px!important;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXdoBy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because `last-child` means it has to be the last child of the parent. Applying it to `.button` does not mean "last child button", it still has to be the very last child, regardless of if it's a button or not.

What you are basically saying is: apply style if it's a `.button` *AND* if it's the `last-child`

It seems you can use [`last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) instead:

```
.button_account_bar > .button:last-of-type {
    border-top-right-radius: 8px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px !important;
}
```

You can check out browser support for `last-of-type` [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-of-type)

Note that you don't actually need `!important` at all, but you may have some other reason for it so I will leave that for you to decide on.

Comment: ohh...so how to add css in last button of button bar

Comment: support looks really nice http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3, good answer

Comment: @kamienok: I was just about to post that link myself.. not as bad as I first expected

Answer (score 0):

The last button is not the last child of its parent.  You have another element, `.toggle_button_div` as the last child of `.button_account_bar`.

One way to solve it is to wrap the buttons in a new `<div>` and then refer to that in your CSS rule:

```
.button_account_bar > div > .button:last-child {
    ...
```

**[Demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqeOmr)**

Comment: ohh...so how to add css in last button of button bar

Answer (score 0):

In your code `.button_account_bar` is the parent class so it's last child is div which class is "`toggle_button_div`, so style for `".button_account_bar > .button:last-child"` is not working use `div-class="toggle_button_div"` outside the `div-class="button_account_bar"` for proper work of your style, and absolutely your code will work. or you can use `last-of-type` in place of `last-child`